# Faker::File in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I have written rspec for controller. And paperclip is used for file upload. I have supposed to write rspec for pagination. For that I want create multiple entries, each entry should have file with csv extension and each file name should be unique.

For that I have move on to Faker gem for generating fake files.

I have tried like

> `30.times { Post.create!(file: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Faker::File.file_name(dir: Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/file', name: "testing_file_#{rand(100)}", ext: 'csv'))) }`

But It will raise an error like

```
RuntimeError: /Users/*/**/spec/fixtures/file/testing_file_28.csv file does not exist
```

I have no idea, about FAKER::FILE. Is there is any way to succeed this approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does the file `testing_file_28.csv` really exist in that path? AFAIK, Faker does not generate files, but will just load one that you do have in your directory (source: https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/file.md)
2. Why do you need `Faker` for that? Would

```rb
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/testing_file_#{rand(100)}.csv", 'application/csv')
```

also do the job?

3. consider using `Rails.root.join('foo', 'bar')` over `Rails.root + "foo/bar"` to avoid troubles with path separators (i.e. `/` vs. `\` depending on your OS). If you go with Faker, and you pass the separator manually, consider using `File::Separator` from the Ruby kernel, see: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html
4. Since it is a CSV file, you could also write a method, that just generates random CSVs, using `CSV.generate`. CSV, in the end, is just a string with `,` and `;`/`\n` as separators. This you can just pass as IO object to `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new`, i.e. no need for physical files bloating your spec folder.